# nested json to csv convert

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to extract nested json values and make csv. So far i have this code:

```
import json
import csv


# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open('test.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

employee_data = data['cn']

data1 = []

# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

header = ['firstName','lastName','jobtitle','company','workPostalCode','workCity','workStreet','mobilePhone','email']
csv_writer.writerow(header)
store = {"firstName":None, "lastName":None, "jobtitle":None, "company":None, "workPostalCode":None, "workCity":None, "workStreet":None, "mobilePhone":None, "email":None}

for emp in employee_data:
    # Writing data of CSV file
    #csv_writer.writerow(emp['_attrs'].values())
    try:
        store['firstName'] = emp["_attrs"]['firstName']
        store['lastName'] = emp["_attrs"]['lastName']
        store['jobtitle'] = emp["_attrs"]['jobtitle']
        store['company'] = emp["_attrs"]['company']
        store['workPostalCode'] = emp["_attrs"]['workPostalCode']
        store['workCity'] = emp["_attrs"]['workCity']
        store['workStreet'] = emp["_attrs"]['workStreet']
        store['mobilePhone'] = emp["_attrs"]['mobilePhone']
        store['email'] = emp["_attrs"]['email']
    except KeyError:
        print('d')
    
    data1.append(store)

    csv_writer.writerow(data1)
    data1 = []

data_file.close()
```

But i need only values from list to be written to csv. Now i have csv like this

```
firstName,lastName,jobtitle,company,workPostalCode,workCity,workStreet,mobilePhone,email

"{'firstName': 'Adnan', 'lastName': 'xxx', 'jobtitle': None, 'company': None, 'workPostalCode': None, 'workCity': None, 'workStreet': None, 'mobilePhone': None, 'email': None}"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be mixing ideas about csv.writer and csv.DictWriter; it looks like you want to write a dict to CSV, which means you should be using the DictWriter.

I guessed that your JSON looks something like this:

```json
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "_attrs": {
                "firstName": "Alice",
                "lastName": "Cheng",
                "jobtitle": "Guru",
                "company": "Acme",
                "workPostalCode": "12345",
                "workCity": "Anytown",
                "workStreet": "Any Street",
                "mobilePhone": "555-5555",
                "email": "alice@acme.com",
                "extraAttr1":"foo",
                "extraAttr2":"bar",
                "extraAttr3":"baz"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

*(note that I added extra attrs 1-3)*

If the JSON object does have more attributes than you want in your CSV, you can easily control what the DictWriter turns to CSV by giving it the field names you care about and instructing it to *ignore extra* fieldnames it finds as it writes each row (dict) to CSV.

I open the JSON I shared above and keep the _attrs dict of each employee dict:

```py
with open("input.json") as f:
    employee_attrs = [emp["_attrs"] for emp in json.load(f)["employees"]]
```

`employee_attrs` looks like:

```py
[
    {
        "firstName": "Alice","lastName": "Cheng","jobtitle": "Guru","company": "FooBar",
        "workPostalCode": "12345","workCity": "Anytown","workStreet": "Any Street","mobilePhone": "555-5555","email": "alice@foobar.com",
        "extraAttr1": "foo","extraAttr2": "bar","extraAttr3": "baz",
    }
]
```

Then I create the DictWriter with the fieldnames I care about and set its extrasaction to "ignore":

```py
my_fieldnames = [
    "firstName","lastName","jobtitle","company",
    "workPostalCode","workCity","workStreet","mobilePhone","email",
]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=my_fieldnames, extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(employee_attrs)
```

And I get the following output.csv (without attrs 1-3):

```
firstName,lastName,jobtitle,company,workPostalCode,workCity,workStreet,mobilePhone,email
Alice,Cheng,Guru,FooBar,12345,Anytown,Any Street,555-5555,alice@foobar.com
```